# Shopping Cart Error Message - Show Remaining Quantity When Quantity Selected Exceeds Inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, error, shopping-cart

Whenever trying to add a quantity to the Magento cart that exceeds the quantity available, the guessing game begins with a message such as, "The requested quantity for 'SOME PRODUCT' is not available."

We want this message to actually show the available quantity.

Please provide the necessary changes in Magento to actually retrieve the available stock quantity and display this in the error message so the customer can change the quantity accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes hard to know where to begin in Magento to add functionality. If you just want the answer, skip down to the bottom. This is how I did it:

**Search app/code/core/Mage for part of the text:**

In my case I searched for the words "Out of stock" - and it returned 21 files. So instead I searched for the phrase "Currently out of stock" and it returned only 6 matches in 5 files. One of these had to be it.

In reading through the list of files, one of them was for XmlConnect (for mobile), 3 were for Wishlist. That only left one result that was relevant:

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php
```

So I know where the message is now. I need to create a module and a rewrite the method `checkQuoteItemQty`, but - geez - that's a really hairy method; a lot of functionality going on in there... probably don't want to copy and paste the entire method. There's probably a better way...

**Creating the rewrite:**

Create a new module. Create a Model folder and create a folder path like  `app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Stock/Item.php` and tell your new class to extend `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`.

You'll create a method there called `checkQuoteItemQty`, and create the model rewrite in your config xml:

```
<models>
    <cataloginventory>
        <rewrite>
            <stock_item>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
        </rewrite>
    </cataloginventory>
</models>
```

Your model's method will look something like this - and this is the tricky part because you have to test the return error value and then load in the catalog product quantity:

```
public function checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty = 0)
{
    $result = parent::checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty);
    if($result->getMessage()==Mage::helper('core')->__('This product is currently out of stock.')){
          $message = Mage::helper('core')->__('Your new message goes in here - items available: %s',$this->getStockQty());
          $result->setMessage($message);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Conclusion**

We created a new module, rewrote the parent, *called the parent* from our rewrite, and tested its return value. If the value of the error message matched our desired text, we rewrite it to include the stock amount left.